# Excel File Corruption when downloading in remote Angular App

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, excel

I have a piece of code that downloads excel reports which works absolutely perfectly on my local web server but when deployed the excel file is always corrupted, code samples below:

AngularJS:

```
$scope.getExcelFile = function(dateFrom, dateTo){

 API.getExcelFile(dateFrom, dateTo).then(function(data){
    var blob = {
     data: [data.data],
      filename: 'ExcelFile.xlsx',
    options: {
      type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
    }
  }
  FileSaver.saveAs(blob);
});
}
```

API(JS):

```
this.getExcelFile= function(dateFrom, dateTo){
    var promise = $http({
        url: '/some/api/endpoint/' + dateFrom + '/' + dateTo,
        method:'GET',
       responseType: 'arraybuffer'
 })
    return promise;
```

PHP API - Note I can't provide all the code for the way this is created but I think it's safe to say it's to do with server/response issues rather than file construction since it works fine locally..

```
 $excelFileName = "ExcelFile.xlsx";
  $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
  header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $excelFileName . '"');
  header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
  $objWriter->save('php://output'); // Output to browser
```

One thing I have noticed is different is that the remote response has a blank line before all the excel binary stuff when I look at it in the chrome inspector, locally it doesn't have this.

Any suggestions around how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok rather embarrassingly this was the result of a stray newline after the closing ?> on a configuration script at the top of the API. Hence the blank newline in the response.

Ideally you shouldn't use ?> at the bottom of PHP scripts at all any more, this was a legacy script.

(face palm)